# Sum of alternating series $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{2i-1}$ with accuracy of $\pm .05$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series is:

> $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{2i-1}$$

I have already shown that it converges but am lost on finding the sum. I need to find the sum to within $\pm .05$.

Comment: for strictly alternating series with strictly decreasing terms (absolute values) the sum lies between any two consecutive  partial sums

Answer (score 4):

You have

- $\left|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{2i-1} - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{2i-1} \right| \leq \frac{1}{2n+1}$ according to [Leibniz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)
- So, solve $\frac{1}{2n+1} <= 0.05 = \frac{1}{20} \Rightarrow n \geq \frac{19}{2} \Rightarrow \color{blue}{\boxed{N = 10}}$
- Calculate $\sum_{i=1}^{\color{blue}{10}} \frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{2i-1}$

Comment: So I calculated the sum and got .7604. Is that the upper bound? What about the lower bound?

Comment: @Bryn Burns:  You get the two bounds as follows: Let's use the abbreviations $S =  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{2i-1}$ and $S_{n}= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{2i-1}$. Then, you have
$$\left|S - S_n \right| \leq \frac{1}{2n+1} \Leftrightarrow -\frac{1}{2n+1} \leq S - S_n \leq \frac{1}{2n+1} \Leftrightarrow S_n -\frac{1}{2n+1} \leq S \leq S_n +\frac{1}{2n+1} $$
So, a lower bound for $S$ within the given accuracy is $S_{10}-\frac{1}{21}$ and an upper bound is $S_{10} + \frac{1}{21}$.